# Can I parse a url with an env variable?

Tags: docker-compose, yaml, environment-variables, settings

**in docker-compose.yaml**

environment:

```
TEST_URL: 'https://something.com/api'
```

**in settings.yaml**

```
partners:
      calculation_url:${CALCULATION_URL:"${TEST_URL}/v1.0/rest/vehicle/insurance/v5/calculation"}
```

I would like to place the URL `https://something.com/api` into a variable and then use it in settings.yaml. Is it possible to use `${TEST_URL}` in the `calculation_url`? I need to change multiple URLs in a similar way, but this approach doesn't seem to work.

I tried to launch the application with the modified environment as described, but it seems that the URL format is not correct. Is it possible to adjust the environment settings to make it work, or is this approach not feasible at all?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include whatever code you've tried so far

Comment: @Barmar I think you're correct! I'm going to remove the [tag:python] tag since this doesn't look like a Python question and that's where I got hung up

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use environment variables to dynamically configure URLs in your applications. The approach you've outlined is almost correct, but there are a few adjustments you need to make to achieve your desired outcome.

In your docker-compose.yaml file, you've defined an environment variable named TEST_URL with the value 'https://something.com/api'.

In your settings.yaml file, you're attempting to use this environment variable within the partners configuration section to construct a dynamic URL for the calculation_url.

Here's how you can achieve this:

Update your docker-compose.yaml:

```
environment:
  TEST_URL: 'https://something.com/api'
```

This sets the TEST_URL environment variable to 'https://something.com/api'.

Update your settings.yaml:

```
partners:
  calculation_url: ${CALCULATION_URL:${TEST_URL}/v1.0/rest/vehicle/insurance/v5/calculation}
```

Here, you're using the ${CALCULATION_URL:${TEST_URL}/v1.0/rest/vehicle/insurance/v5/calculation} syntax. This means that if the CALCULATION_URL environment variable is set, it will be used; otherwise, the value from ${TEST_URL}/v1.0/rest/vehicle/insurance/v5/calculation will be used as the default.

Now, when you launch your application using the modified environment as described above, the URL should be constructed correctly. Just make sure that the syntax is precise, and you have the proper indentation in your YAML files.

If you've tried this approach and the URL format still appears incorrect, please double-check your YAML syntax and ensure that the environment variables are being passed correctly to your application. Also, ensure that the application you're using supports this kind of dynamic URL configuration through environment variables.